# how to pass an array argument to inline onblur in jquery html string

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to add inline onblur event listener with html string which I am updating using jQuery append method.

jQuery append in working fine, I also send arguments inline onblur event, it also works fine but when I am trying to send an array it gives me an error

> SyntaxError: expected expression, got '}'

Here is my code:
php (html code):

```
<button onclick="addArea('<?= $value ?>','<?=htmlentities(json_encode($area_state)) ?>')">
```

in jQuery

```
function addArea(value, area_state){
    var content = "<table style = 'height: 450px;' class='table font_area table-borderless date_time' id='area_values'><input type=text onblur=saveAreaValue('"+colName+"', '"+area_state+"')>";
}
```

In jQuery, the format of area_state array is:

> ["Detection Clear","Detection On","Detection Uncertain","Not
>   Operational","Detection Error","Created","Not Created","Deleted"]

Am I missing something here, can some one help?

Comment: What does the rendered HTML look like?

Comment: <input type="text" onblur="saveAreaValue('Name'," '["detection="" clear","detection="" on","detection="" uncertain","not="" operational","detection="" error","created","not="" created","deleted"]')="">

Comment: Please update your QUESTION with relevant HTML There is nothing here that is relevant to PHP unless we see the rendering of the HTML

Comment: Showing the PHP method used *is* at least a good starting point for figuring out how to send the data to the HTML better (but seeing the rendered HTML too helps a lot)

Comment: Wonder why PHP is thinking `["detection="" clear","detection="" on",` is JSON? That seems pretty strange

Comment: I also passed same array in HTML and it works fine
     <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg" onclick="unAllocatedLight('<?= $value; ?>','<?=htmlentities(json_encode($area_light)) ?>')" style="background-color: #06A28A; color: white;">Add</button>

but when I am trying to pass the array inline jQuery function, it gives me an error